# NInject instantiating multiple services

Tags: ninject, decorator

I configured decorators as follows

```
Bind<IEmailService>().To<EmailService>().WhenInjectedInto<LoggerEmailService>();
Bind<IEmailService>().To<LoggerEmailService>().WhenInjectedInto<ExceptionHandlerEmailService>();
Bind<IEmailService>().To<ExceptionHandlerEmailService>();
```

When I place a break point in the ctor of service implementation, like ExceptionHandlerEmailService or just EmailService, I find that the service is called multiple times. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

.InSingletonScope() is what is needed.

```
Bind<IEmailService>().To<ExceptionHandlerEmailService>().InSingletonScope();
Bind<IEmailService>().To<LoggerEmailService>().WhenInjectedInto<ExceptionHandlerEmailService>();
Bind<IEmailService>().To<EmailService>().WhenInjectedInto<LoggerEmailService>();
```